# Getting "Type 'FieldValue' has no member 'arrayUnion'" when adding element to Firestore array

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When I use this code in Xcode:

```
let washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC")

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"])
])

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "regions": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["east_coast"])
])
```

which is an example in [Firebase Website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), I get the following error:

```
Type 'FieldValue' has no member 'arrayUnion'
```

any solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you have an "old" version of the iOS SDK. The arrayUnion feature has been implemented in Version 5.5.0, dated August 2, 2018.

See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios for more detail.